# elastic search phrase suggestor not removing spaces from text

Tags: elasticsearch

elastic search suggestor not removing unwanted spaces
query used...

```
POST /_search
{
  "_source": false,
  "suggest": {
    "text": "mega polis",
    "simple_phrase": {
      "phrase": {
        "field": "address.phonetic",
        "size": 5,
        "confidence": 1,
        "max_errors": 3,
        "gram_size": 2,
        "analyzer": "trigram",
        "direct_generator": [
          {
            "suggest_mode": "always",
            "field": "address.phonetic",
            "size": 10,
            "prefix_length": 0
          }
        ],
        "highlight": {
          "pre_tag": "<em>",
          "post_tag": "</em>"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have indexed data **megapolis** and if i enter search text **mega polis**
it is not correcting to **megapolis**
I have used ngram analyzer min_shingle_size=2 and max_shingle_size=3

Answer (score 0):

Have you found a good solution to this?

I'm not sure if this is the best way, but in my case a simple solution was to switch to the `term`-suggester. To keep the full input as a single term I used the `keyword`-analyzer. I guess your `trigram`-analyzer will do the trick as well, and it's probably preferable when dealing with longer input texts.

```
GET myindex/_search
{
  "suggest": {
    "did_you_mean": {
      "text": "orddelings feil",
      "term": {
        "analyzer": "keyword",
        "field": "title"
      }
    }
  }
}
```